# UWP App Clipboard Access: how to prevent processing the same items multiple times

Tags: uwp, clipboard, windows-10-universal

When accessing the Win10 clipboard from an UWP app, the app can only check the clipboard when in focus.
So the app has no idea what happend while it was asleep.
Upon focus, it can check the contents again.

Now the question: How do it determine that the `DataPackageView` from `Clipboard.GetContents()` is a fresh package rather than one that it already looked at? There seems to be no ID in `DataPackageView.Properties` or anything else that might be used to differentiate.

I had hoped that `DataPackageView.GetHashCode()` might be the answer but had to find that the `DataPackageView` seems to be instantiated anew every time a `GetContents()` call is made, so no luck there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, did not get anything fast enough. Suggestions about **ClipboardHistory** are unfortunately mute as that can be disabled (and IMHO should be)...

I am working with **bitmap contents** so storing the clipboard contents to a file and then hashing the file failed as the resulting file might get meta-tagged and thus will produce a different hash even though the bitmaps are identical.

The only way to somewhat ensure that the bitmap itself has not been seen is to hash pixel arrays... Could still leave you with an identical hash result, but that's a risk I am willing to take. There is a bit of grumbling about memory but if I want to show the bitmap I better have the memory to load it. NASA, this won't work for you out of the box...

So I decided to do the hard slog and hash the bitmap itself.

```
public async Task<String> GetBitmapHashAsync(StorageFile sourceFile)
{
    string result = null;

    // load the bitmap file into a bitmap-decoder and run a Hash algo on the actual pixels
    try
    {
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await sourceFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
            PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();

            // Get the pixel data
            byte[] sourcePixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

            SHA512 sha512Hasher = SHA512.Create();

            // and feed it to the Hasher
            byte[] data = sha512Hasher.ComputeHash(sourcePixels);

            // And now enjoy the result as a HEX string
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            result = sBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> UWP App Clipboard Access: how to prevent processing the same items multiple times

`Clipboard` contains `GetHistoryItemsAsync` method that use to get `ClipboardHistoryItemsResult`. You could call `ClipboardHistoryItemsResult.Items` to get `ClipboardHistoryItem`.  ClipboardHistoryItem has id property to notify the difference.

```
var results = await Clipboard.GetHistoryItemsAsync();
var id = results.Items.Last().Id;
```

And if the last items id has not changed, it means that there is no new item inserting into  clipboard. Please note that it cannot be used to verify that the contents of the DataPackageView are the same.

if you want to verify `DataPackageView`, please get last two items and compare separately.

Comment: Nico, might I suggest in the next UWP iteration that you add Clipboard IDs as supported in `ClipboardHistory` to the `DataPackageView` of `Clipboart.GetContent()`?

Comment: Sure, please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back app.